# "aborted (core dumped)" in all programs

Tags: c

yesterday, during programming time everything was okay, but today I get weird error. I do not know why but after running my programs, in terminal i get this error "aborted (core dumped)", also I run programs which are already done and the problem is the same. 
Example of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define CHUNK 12

char *getWord(FILE *infile);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *word;
    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    int n = 0;

    if(argc != 2) 
    {
        printf("Error! Type:./file_name input_file output_file\n");
        abort();
    }

    infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(infile != NULL)
    {
        outfile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
        if(outfile == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! Cannot open the output_file\n");
            abort();
        }
        else
        {
            while(!feof(infile))
            {
                word = getWord(infile);
                if(word == NULL)
                {
                    free(word);
                    abort();
                }

                n++;
                if(n % 2 == 0)
                {
                    fputs(word, outfile);
                    fputs(" ", outfile);
                }
                else 
                {
                    fputs(word, outfile);
                    fputs("(", outfile);
                    fputs(word, outfile);
                    fputs(")", outfile);
                    fputs(" ", outfile);
                }
                    free(word);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error! Cannot open the input_file\n");
        abort();
    }

    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}

char *getWord(FILE *infile)
{
    char *word, *word2;
    int length, cursor, c;

    word = malloc(sizeof(char)*CHUNK);
    if(word == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    length = CHUNK;
    cursor = 0;

    while(isalpha(c = getc(infile)) && !feof(infile))
    {
        word[cursor] = c;
        cursor++;

        if(cursor >= length)
        {
            length += CHUNK;
            word2 = realloc(word, length*sizeof(char));
            if(word2 == NULL)
            {
                free(word2);
                return NULL;
            }
            else word2 = word;
        }
    }

    ungetc(c, infile);
    word[cursor] = '\0';
    return word;
}
```

and the error:

```
Error! Type:./file_name input_file output_file
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: use `valgrind` tool to diagnose such errors.

Comment: `if(word == NULL) { free(word);` yikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your command requires 2 parameters, you need to check for `argc != 3` since the command name itself is considered an argument. If you are giving it 2 parameters, then your check on `argc != 2` is failing and you're getting your error message, and the core dump due to the `abort` call.

Rather than `abort`, you should call `exit` with a non-zero parameter. E.g.,

```
if(argc != 3) 
{
    printf("Error! Type: %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: even better, use `argv[0]` for the program name

Answer (score 4):

The logic in your `realloc` is wrong.

```
word2 = realloc(word, length*sizeof(char));
if(word2 == NULL)
{
    free(word2);
    return NULL;
}
else word2 = word;
```

should be

```
word2 = realloc(word, cursor);
if(word2 == NULL)
{
    free(word);
    return NULL;
}
word = word2;
```

There are a few changes here

- `word` starts out having `length` bytes allocated so there is no point in reallocating it to the same size.  The variable which tracks string size is `cursor` so you need to reallocate to match its size.
- (minor) There is no need to use `sizeof(char)` to help calculate the size of an allocation - this is guaranteed to be 1
- If `realloc` fails, you need to `free` the original pointer, not the new one (which you know is `NULL`).
- If the reallocation succeeds, your heap cell may have been moved, leaving `word` pointing to memory you don't own.  The rest of the function operates on `word` so you need to update it to point to your new buffer (`word2`)

As for why this worked for you previously, the above code results in undefined behaviour in a number of places.  Sometimes you're unlucky and this appears to work correctly.